# State Transitions in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

Is it possible to customise the transitions between states on work items on VSTS? I have some custom states and want to restrict what the next available states are.

For example when a new bug is raised in the 'New' state the user should only able to select 'In Progress', 'Rejected' etc. But they should not be able to selected 'Closed'

This was possible in TFS but I can't find anywhere in VSTS to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to add restrictions to the state workflow using work item rules. Though there may be a couple of tricks by clearing a field, making it read-only and making it required when the state is changed to an undesirable state.

Work Item rules were a recent addition and not all restrictions from the old XML model are currently supported.

When you import a TFS collection into VSTS there is an option to keep using the XML model to manage processes. Those accounts do support many of the old configuration options and restrictions.